# error MSB3073: The command "staticdv.exe /devenv /check" exited with code -1

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2015, driver, ndis

I have a NDIS 6 filter driver. It is a packet capture driver based on the official [ndislwf](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/network/ndis/filter) example. The whole project is open sourced on [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/nmap/npcap/tree/master/packetWin7/npf). `npf.sln` can be opened via `Visual Studio 2015`.

My problem is the [Static Driver Verifier (SDV)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552808(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't work on my project. When I clicked `Driver` -> `Launch Static Driver Verifier...` on `Visual Studio 2015`, it popped up the SDV GUI, then I clicked `Clean` and `Start`. After a while (3-5 minutes), a window popped up saying *SDV encountered an error of unknown origin.*. And the `Alerts` tab of the SDV UI said:

```
J:\npcap\packetWin7\npf\npf>cd /d "J:\npcap\packetWin7\npf\npf"   && msbuild "npf.vcxproj" /t:sdv /p:inputs="/devenv /check" /p:configuration="Win7 Release SDV" /p:platform="x64"  
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Build started 7/25/2016 12:42:39 PM.
Project "J:\npcap\packetWin7\npf\npf\npf.vcxproj" on node 1 (sdv target(s)).
sdv:
  staticdv.exe /devenv /check
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Static Driver Verifier Version 4.0.505.8
  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  SDV is building for <Win7 Release SDV|x64>
  Build     'npf' ... Done
  Scan      'npf' ... Done
  No reuse data to copy from previous SDV run.
  The finalization step failed for   'npf' .
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\windowsdriver.Sdv.targets(65,9): error MSB3073: The command "staticdv.exe /devenv /check" exited with code -1. [J:\npcap\packetWin7\npf\npf\npf.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "J:\npcap\packetWin7\npf\npf\npf.vcxproj" (sdv target(s)) -- FAILED.
Build FAILED.
"J:\npcap\packetWin7\npf\npf\npf.vcxproj" (sdv target) (1) ->
(sdv target) -> 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\windowsdriver.Sdv.targets(65,9): error MSB3073: The command "staticdv.exe /devenv /check" exited with code -1. [J:\npcap\packetWin7\npf\npf\npf.vcxproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:01:30.61
```

Then I looked at the `StaticDVTrace.log` log. It said as below:

```
Information:Calling DriverCleanup.
Information:Creating a new SDV object.
Information:Loading cache data.
Information:Calling cleanup routine.
Information:Creating a new SDV object.
Information:SetBase this.DdkPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
Information:SetBase this.Path=J:\npcap\packetWin7\npf\npf
Information:SetBase creating the DriverCollection via constructor.
Information:Driver Constructor:Calling RuleCollection constructor with rule list and rule path
Information:SetBase this.Environment=WDK
Information:SetBase Calling InitBaseEnvironment.
Information:Check that we have driver folder.
Information:Calling build to get cl and link flags.
Information:GenerateBuildLogNewCall build.exe.
Information:GenerateBuildLogNewCall to build.exe worked.
Information:Build     'npf' ... Done
Information:Found Sdv links file and attempting to serialize the data into our object model.
Information:Found Sdv source file and attempting to serialize the data into our object model.
Information:Found cflags in Sdv source file.
Information:Slam model equals 
Information:Slam rules equals 
Information:Slam Data equals 
Information:Calling OpenNewConfiguration
Information:SetBase this.DdkPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
Information:SetBase this.Path=J:\npcap\packetWin7\npf\npf
Information:SetBase  Opening All.sdv to load active rule list.
Information:OpenMsft Opening All.sdv from:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\TOOLS\SDV\data\ndis\All.sdv
Information:OpenMsft Reading :C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\TOOLS\SDV\data\ndis\All.sdv
Information:OpenMsft Adding :DDIUSAGE.SDV.fsm to the list of rules.
Information:OpenMsft Adding :IRQL.SDV.fsm to the list of rules.
Information:OpenMsft Adding :IRQL_SHARED.SDV.fsm to the list of rules.
Information:OpenMsft Adding :LOCKING.SDV.fsm to the list of rules.
Information:OpenMsft Adding :MEMORYUSAGE.SDV.fsm to the list of rules.
Information:OpenMsft Adding :MISCELLANEOUS.SDV.fsm to the list of rules.
Information:OpenMsft Adding :OIDPROCESSING.SDV.fsm to the list of rules.
Information:OpenMsft Adding :WARNING.SDV.fsm to the list of rules.
Information:OpenMsft Adding :.fsm to the list of rules.
Information:SetBase Calling driver constructor.
Information:RuleCollection Constructor:Calling Rule Constructor.
Information:RuleCollection Constructor:add rule object to collection.
...
Information:RuleCollection Constructor:Calling Rule Constructor.
Information:RuleCollection Constructor:add rule object to collection.
Information:SetBase this.Environment=WDK
Information:SetBase Calling InitBaseEnvironment.
Information:this.NumberOfChecks=0100
Information:this.NumberOfNotStarted=100
Information:Opening sdv-default.xml from:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\TOOLS\SDV\data\ndis
Information:SdvScan:Local sdv-default.xml found.
Information:Calling build to get cl and link flags.
Information:Loading library data from cache at:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
Information:Loading build data.
Information:Counting the LOC in the driver.
Information:Loading WDM entry points from :C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\TOOLS\SDV\data\ndis\DdkEntryPoints.xml
Information:Calling CheckScan to validate we have a valid SDV-map.h file.
Information:CheckScan:Generating SDV-map.h file via call to SdvMap.
Information:SdvMap:Iterate over each driver in the collection.
Information:BuildLib:Create sdv folder.
Information:BuildLib:Create sdv\scan folder.
7/25/2016 11:00:08 PM:The SDV-map.h file at: J:\npcap\packetWin7\npf\npf.
Information:The SDV-map.h file at:J:\npcap\packetWin7\npf\npf does not have the "Approved" flag set to "true."
Information:Scan      'npf' ... Done
Information:CheckScan:Calling LoadSdvMap.
Information:Check if debug flags are set.
Information:Start sdv scan step via call to SdvScan.
Information:SdvScan:Calling SetupSdvScanFolders
Information:SdvScan:Checking if we have a local version of sdv-default.xml
Information:BuildLib:Create sdv folder.
Information:BuildLib:Create sdv\scan folder.
Information:Copying old reuse data for this run...J:\npcap\packetWin7\npf\npf
Information:No reuse data to copy from previous SDV run.
Information:Calling the SdvCheck stage.
Information:SdvCheck:Calling CleanupCflags.
Information:SdvCheck:Calling SetupSdvCheckFolders.
Information:SdvCheck:Calling RuleSpec.
Information:RuleSpec:.
Information:RuleSpec:Calling CompileStage for 
Information:RuleSpec:Calling CompileStage for pre_isminiport.fsm
7/25/2016 11:00:16 PM:The SDV compile step failed.
```

I can't tell anything from the error message. Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to [approve the `sdv-map.h` file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/devtest/approving-the-sdv-map-h-file). Open the `sdv-map.h` file that SDV generated in your source directory, verify that everything looks correct, then change `//Approved=false` to `//Approved=true`.